# show sum of numbers on jquery sortable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm try to make some thing like this with jQuery :

To show sum of numbers inside gray `spans`, so user can sort `div` and find the sum of numbers in `spans`

But it is not working.

Here is my code;

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("#menu").sortable({
 
 stop:function(){    
    
 $("#s1").text(parseInt($('#a1').text())+parseInt($('#a2').text())+parseInt($('#a3').text()));
 
 $("#s2").text(parseInt($('#b1').text())+parseInt($('#b2').text())+parseInt($('#b3').text()));
 
 $("#s3").text(parseInt($('#c1').text())+parseInt($('#c2').text())+parseInt($('#c3').text()));
 
 $("#s4").text(parseInt($('#a1').text())+parseInt($('#b1').text())+parseInt($('#c1').text()));
 
 $("#s5").text(parseInt($('#a2').text())+parseInt($('#b2').text())+parseInt($('#c2').text()));
 
 $("#s6").text(parseInt($('#a3').text())+parseInt($('#b3').text())+parseInt($('#c3').text()));
 
   
 }
   });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#main{
 width:960px;
 height:700px;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 }
#menu {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 
}

#menu li {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 float:left;
 list-style-type:none;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:100px;
}

#menu #a1 {
 background-color: #FF9AA9;
 
}
#menu #a2 {
 background-color: #FF8AA9;
 
}
#menu #a3 {
 background-color: #FF7AA9;
 
}
#menu #b1 {
 background-color: #FF6AA9;
 
}
#menu #b2 {
 background-color: #6269F8;
 
}
#menu #b3 {
 background-color: #F3FF79;
 
}
#menu #c1 {
 background-color: #6EF8A4;
 
}
#menu #c2 {
 background-color: #88BAFF;
 
}
#menu #c3 {
 background-color: #B878E9;
 
}
.spn{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 position:absolute;
 background-color:gray;
 }

#s1{
 top:25px;
 left:700px;
 }
#s2{
 top:125px;
 left:700px;
 }
#s3{
 top:225px;
 left:700px;
 }
#s4{
 top:350px;
 left:575px;
 }
#s5{
 top:350px;
 left:475px;
 }
#s6{
 top:350px;
 left:375px;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body><br>
<div id="main">    
    <ul id="menu">
    
          <li class="cld" id="a1">18</li>
          <li class="cld" id="a2">13</li>
          <li class="cld" id="a3">12</li>
        
          <li class="cld" id="b1">20</li>
          <li class="cld" id="b2">19</li>
          <li class="cld" id="b3">9</li>
                  
          <li class="cld" id="c1">14</li>
          <li class="cld" id="c2">8</li>
          <li class="cld" id="c3">7</li>
       
    </ul>

<span class="spn" id="s1"></span>
<span class="spn" id="s2"></span>
<span class="spn" id="s3"></span>
<span class="spn" id="s4"></span>
<span class="spn" id="s5"></span>
<span class="spn" id="s6"></span>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"but it is not working!"_ That's no informative description of the error... What is (not) happening? What should happen instead? Any error messages in the console?

Comment: The snippet is working...

Comment: The sum of the values are executed on drag end when you rearrange the elements. The only problem I see is that rearrange the sum is the same, because you are making the sum with IDs and the blocks has the same id no matter in what position is.

Comment: :D thanks marcos   that was my problem i have to get li with #menu li:nth-child(9)  , #menu li:nth-child(8)  and ..........